# Adding array of dictionary to array of dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I had two `NSDictionary` elements in the `finalOrderArray` before `addingObject`. Then I added `sharedData.comboItems` but this object is also an array of `NSDictionary`.

Now,I have a mix of `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` which is difficult to handle.

Is there **an easy way** to add `NSDictionary` all together?

```
[finalOrderArray addObject:sharedData.comboItems];
```

[image]

Desired output in this example, `finalOrderArray` would have 6 dictionaries rather than having 2 dictionaries and one array of dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `addObjectsFromArray:` method.

> Adds the objects contained in another given array to the end of the
>   receiving array’s content.

Here is the [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablearray?language=objc) to `NSMutableArray` and all its methods.

Answer (score 1):

Use `addObjectsFromArray` method. It will add all the objects from sharedData.comboItems. Try this.

```
[finalOrderArray addObjectsFromArray: sharedData.comboItems];
```

Answer (score 0):

`sharedData.comboItems` is an array that's why you get one array in your finalOrderArray. You need to iterate through the array, get the dictionary and add to finalOrderArray.

**Like this:**

```
for (NSDictionary *item in sharedData.comboItems) {
   [finalOrderArray addObject:item];
}
```

Comment: Is there a short way to handling this issue without looping it?